# google+ follow button not showing properly in bootstrap modal in firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-plus

I have a bootstrap modal inside that i have google+ follow button it is showing properly in google chrome but not showing in firefox. i tried putting in normal page and its working fine but i want it in the modal box.

here is my code.

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="sharing_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">   
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content sharing-wrapper">

          <div class="modal-body sharing-body">
                <img src="/assets/google-round.png" width="80px;" class="img-centered">

            <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>

            <div class="g-follow" data-annotation="vertical-bubble" data-height="24" data-href="https://plus.google.com/104729765568883320527" data-rel="publisher"></div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the style "display: none" of the bootstrap modal. Because of this the google+ follow button doesn't calculate the right size in Firefox.

As a workaround you could overwrite the css style to "display: block" and after pageload you set it back to "display: none".

Example CSS:

```
#sharing_modal
{
    display: block;
}
```

Example JS (JQuery):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#sharing_modal').css('display', 'none');
});
```

See this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rvuqyjf9/1/